# IPython won't start

Tags: python, ipython

I'm running Windows 7 x64. I installed the 32x verson of Python 2.7.2 and IPython 0.11 using the Windows Installers. They installed all right. I added C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts to the system envorment variables.

When I type ipython in the command prompt I get this message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 5, in 
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

How to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solution. Also need to install `setuptools` from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: What about version installing ipython with Python v 3.2 .. I couldn't find a version of setuptools for this under windows.

Comment: how to install it on windows machine? - edited; okay I got it,  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files

Comment: for those who search for x64 bit version of `setuptools` for 3.3 there is currently a problem with it hence there isn't a binary installer.