# Where to use ipython and where is ipthon shell?

Tags: python, ipython

I've installed ipython, but I don't know how to use it. Where could I find ipython shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

open up your terminal, type `ipython` and run.

EDIT: have you set `ipython` in your environment variables? [Here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/config/initial_config.html) is an initial configurations guide by ipython.org

EDIT: maybe you also need to install setuptools from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

source: [IPython won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287422/ipython-wont-start)

Comment: have you set ipython in your environment variables?

Comment: @JeffS @dciriello I did it now. Now I have this error: `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

Comment: maybe you also need to install setuptools from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: Thank you too. Setuptools builds on Python’s distutils to provide easier building, distribution, and installation of libraries and applications.

Answer (score 4):

To use ipython, just go to the command line, and run the command `ipython`.

Comment: I'm doing it but it says: `'ipython' is not recognized as an internal or external command,...` I have python 2.7 and I installed __ipython-0.13.1.py2-win32-PROPER.exe__. What could be wrong?

Comment: ipython may not be in your `PATH`, see where the ipython executable is, and then add that directory to your path environment variable

Answer (score 3):

> You start IPython with the command:
>
> `$ ipython [options] files`

See http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#command-line-usage

You either have to be in the directory that has ipython installed, or add the directory to the path.

You can do this by `Alt` double clicking on `My Computer`, select `Advanced Options`, `Environment`, find the `PATH` environment variable and add the directory where `ipython` is installed.

Start a new command prompt and typing `ipython` should start the interpreter.